# UIPageControl wont update the page I am on

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, uipagecontrol

I have this method that allows a `UIPageControl` to be displayed and show images based on an `NSArray` of images on the web. It sort of works ,but it doesn't update image when I change the current page. I am going to use the current page number for the array index the picture needs to be grabbed at. Any tips to make this method update every time you change pages in `UIControlPage` will be appreciated.

```
-(void)method
{           
      pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
      pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 95);
      pageControl.numberOfPages = pictures.count;

      [pic setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictures[pageControl.currentPage]]
      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
      [image addSubview:pageControl];
}
```

Comment: B.T.W., for anyone looking at this question, the method "`setImageWithURL: placeholderImage:`" appears to [come from SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. Thanks.